# Gmail doesn't consider valid SPF

Tags: php, email, sendmail, spf

According to SPF validation tool available on http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html my domain has correctly configured SPF record: `v=spf1 ip4:111.222.333.444 include:zoho.com ~all`

I'm sending emails from:

- zoho.com (this validates in Gmail and email comes immediately)
- my server via PHP using `sendmail` (this doesn't validate and email comes with about 122 seconds delay)

```
    Delivered-To: my-email@gmail.com
    Received: by 10.107.31.138 with SMTP id 123xxx123xxx123;
            Sun, 9 Apr 2017 04:10:44 -0700 (PDT)
    X-Received: by 10.28.40.198 with SMTP id 567xxx567xxx.567.567567567;
            Sun, 09 Apr 2017 04:10:44 -0700 (PDT)
    Return-Path: 
    Received: from sd-111111.dedibox.fr ([111.222.333.444])
            by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id 12345678.12.2017.04.09.04.13.25
            for 
            (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
            Sun, 09 Apr 2017 04:10:44 -0700 (PDT)
    Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 111.222.333.444 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of www-data@sd-111111.dedibox.fr) client-ip=111.222.333.444;
    Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
           spf=neutral (google.com: 111.222.333.444 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of www-data@sd-111111.dedibox.fr) smtp.mailfrom=www-data@sd-111111.dedibox.fr
    Received: from sd-111111.dedibox.fr (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by sd-111111.dedibox.fr (8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-3) with ESMTP id xxxxxxxxxxx for ; Sun, 9 Apr 2017 13:11:24 +0200
    Received: (from www-data@localhost) by sd-111111.dedibox.fr (8.15.2/8.15.2/Submit) id v39BBO6a028991; Sun, 9 Apr 2017 13:11:24 +0200
    Date: Sun, 9 Apr 2017 13:08:42 +0200
    Message-Id: 
    To: my-email@gmail.com
    Subject: the subject
    X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1000:mail.php
    From: webmaster@my-domain.com
    Reply-To: webmaster@my-domain.com
    X-Mailer: PHP/7.1.3-3+deb.sury.org~xenial+1

    hello
```

How can I fix this?

The message is `Gmail couldn't verify that my-domain.com actually sent this messages (and not a spammer).` and it links to https://support.google.com/mail/answer/180707

(I should point out that I made the SPF record correct many days ago and all DNS servers have surely been updated by now. It currently has TTL set to 30 seconds anyway for several weeks.)

UPDATE: I just noticed that GMail is seeing that the email is sent from `sd-11111.dedibox.fr` and not from `111.222.333.444` but doing `ping sd-11111.dedibox.fr` returns this exact ip: `Reply from 111.222.333.444: bytes=32 time=38ms TTL=52` so I'm still clueless why it doesn't consider the IP?

Comment: `sd-11111.dedibox.fr` doesn't resolve to any IP for me. Is it only defined within your network? If so, Gmail wouldn't be able to resolve it either.

Comment: All IPs, IDs and domain names were replaced with placeholders to conceal private information. Entering `sd-11111.dedibox.fr` or `111.222.333.444` in the browser (port 80) opens exactly the same Apache/PHP homepage.

Comment: Unless this is also caused by your anonymization, it looks like Google are trying to verify the domain listed as "smtp.mailfrom", rather than / as well as the domain listed as "From".

Comment: Anonymized things were: `my-email@gmail.com`, two SMTP ids, ESMTP id, timestamps, `sd-111111.dedibox.fr`, `111.222.333.444` and `webmaster@my-domain.com`. The rest is intact. Therefore, what is attached to "smtp.mailfrom" is not modified except for the domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Without real IP's or domain names, it's going to be hard to help you troubleshoot. Based on the `Make Believe` example everything is fine.

If that's the case, it's usually because you might have a hidden control character or something in your SPF record causing the issue. My suggestion will be to delete your old SPF record and add a new one retyping it.

You can send emails to reflectors such as

```
mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com
check-auth@verifier.port25.com
```

To verify if other mail servers also flag your SPF with an error.

Comment: The SPF record is provided exactly as typed. It's valid. When I update it to `v=spf1 ip4:111.222.333.444 include:sd-11111.dedibox.fr include:zoho.com ~all` I get PermError (it says the newly added domain doesn't have specified SPF record.) Perhaps I should contact the hosting company... but they are just giving me a dedicated server so I think it's not their fault but it's a general configuration question (hence this SO question instead).

Comment: I tested the first mail reflector and it provides useful information. It looks like it may be related to `sendmail` configuration. Maybe I'll be able to sort this out based on this information.

Comment: You added that hostname incorrectly. Don't do it as an `include`, do it as `a:hostname`, because you want to permit that host, not that host's own SPF.

Comment: @Synchro +1 Thanks, now the SPF record works and Gmail recognizes emails as valid! The delay of about 2-3 minutes remains. And since number of domains that can be listed with `a` is limited I still would like to figure out how to add IPs. I'm doing it with trial and error now.